# Difficulty evaluating a complex integral on Griffiths

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, integration, complex-numbers

This actually a question from Griffiths QM. (Q2.21)

I have difficulty understanding integrals involving imaginary components. In this example, it looks like the first term (encircled in red) explodes as it goes to +infinity, however it's neglected. I have difficulty understanding such evaluations in general. If we manipulate the integral's term as -(-ik+a)x, it makes sense but is it OK to do such manipulations?

Can you help me understand how these kind of integration evaluations work in general? I have trouble evaluating similar integrals in general.
[image: Exercise]

Comment: $e^{(ik-a)x}=e^{-ax}(\cos(kx)+i\sin(kx))$, do you agree? Then what happens to each term as $x\to\infty$ (when $a>0$)?

Comment: Rewrite $e^{(ik-a)x}$ as $e^{ikx}e^{-ax}$. The first factor has absolute value of 1 for any $x$, but the second factor goes to 0 for large $x$. Therefore, for large $x$, the entire thing goes to zero.

Comment: @lemon, exp(-ax) goes to 1, but what about cos(kx) and isin(kx)? I don't know how to evaluate periodic and imaginary terms when x diverges to infinity.

Comment: @DanielSank, How should I deal with imaginary compenents in integrals? Should I always make them real by taking their complex conjugates? Can you explain why it has absolute value of 1?

Comment: @erwinschrodinger: I'm confused, you accepted an answer but you're still asking questions. The reason $e^{ikx}$ has absolute value 1 is $|e^{ikx}| = |\cos(kx) + i \sin(kx)| = \sqrt{\cos(kx)^2 + \sin(kx)^2} = 1$.

Comment: @DanielSank, Should I always take the complex comjugates when there are imaginary components on the integration?

Comment: @erwinschrodinger: No. Where did anyone suggest complex conjugates?

Answer (score 1):

> it looks like the first term (encircled in red) explodes as it goes to
>   +infinity,

But it doesn't explode since, for either term, the real part of the exponent $\le 0$.  Write the two numerators as

$$e^{(ik -a)x} = e^{ikx}e^{-ax}$$

and

$$e^{-(ik + a)x} = e^{-ikx}e^{-ax}$$

Over the domain of integration, the numerators are finite.

Comment: Shouldn't real part of the exponent >0? Also, I get the part that exp(-ax) and exp(-ikx) is finite (because 1/(exp(inf) = 1/(inf) = 0, but what about exp(ikx)? Why is it that it doesn't go to infinity? It is because of Euler's identity?

Comment: @erwinschrodinger, $e^{ix}$ has a constant *magnitude* of $1$ and yes, this is easy to see by writing  $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$.  It should be clear, by inspection of the right-most integral in the first line of equations, that the real exponential is decaying.

Answer (score 0):

The term you have highlighted contains a decaying (real) exponential factor $\exp(-ax)$ which goes to 0 for $x \rightarrow 0$. The other factor in that term is a complex exponential which is non-infinite for all $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What can we say about periodic functions that go to infinity? (e.g., cosx).